# combinatorics- choosing a day of the 100 times and proving atleast one day is used 15 times

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how to approach this question as I am quite confused.

> Suppose we choose a day of the week 100 times. For example: ‘Wed’, ‘Mon’, ‘Mon’, ‘Sun’, ‘Sat’
>   and so on. Prove that, no matter what sequence of days we choose (randomly or otherwise) to
>   write down, we must have written down at least one of the days of the week at least 15 times.

Comment: $100=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_7$ where $a_1$ is the number of occurrences of Monday, $a_2$ of Tuesday, etc. What if all $a_j\le 14$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the compliment of the statement is 'all days were selected less than 15 times' which is at most $14×7=98<100$. Hence, the original statement is true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If no weekday is chosen more than $14$ times, how many days can at most have been chosen?